# Android draw with blur

Tags: android, canvas, draw, blur

I need do draw on Android's Canvas using Blur effect, 
it is a very simple feature, 
I need to draw a circular area, which is blurred (the foreground) and the background transparent, I can do everything with manipulating the colour alpha to do it with custom transparency but I need it to be blurred instead of transparent.. 
any ideas?

Answer (score 21):

(For those who are coming back, though this is an old question)

On the Paint object which you are using to draw the Color, set

```
paint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL))
```

Then, in Android Manifest.xml, set

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

for your activity
(Blur doesn't work when hardware acceleration is true)

For more explanation refer
[Android BlurMaskFilter has no effect in canvas.drawOval while text is blurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281404/android-blurmaskfilter-has-no-effect-in-canvas-drawoval-while-text-is-blurred)

Comment: It just blurs to the applied drawing and not the background of it, eg: i draw 2 rectangles on top of each other, top 1 is blurred but it doesn't show effect on background 1

Answer (score 0):

If you're not gonna need to manipulate it afterwards you could just draw to a buffer and blur it yourself pixel by pixel, then blit that buffer to screen when you need to paint it.

Or this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BlurMaskFilter.Blur.html

Comment: Well, BlurMaskFilter, will not cut it since it will only blur the edges, I need the blur to be evenly distributed trough the object (circle), and with blurmaskfilter, I can only "sharpen the edges"

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [Android, Blur Bitmap instantly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435561/android-blur-bitmap-instantly/13435660#comment18387297_13435660)

Again I would recommend you first to draw into a bitmap. Scale it down (try different sizes), and the scale it back up to the original size (either as a new bitmap or if you use hw acceleration do it while you draw).