# Android BlurMaskFilter has no effect in canvas.drawOval while text is blurred

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, blur

I've been trying to create a custom view which has blurred shapes under text. The problem is that the BlurMaskFilter has no effect on any shape that I draw on the canvas. Here is how I'm initialising the Paint objects in the constructor:

```
paint = new Paint(0);
paint.setColor(0xffffffff);
paint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));

mShadowPaint = new Paint(0);
mShadowPaint.setColor(0xff333333);
mShadowPaint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(10, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));
```

And I'm calling the functions like this in onDraw():

```
canvas.drawOval(mShadowBounds,mShadowPaint);
canvas.drawText("hello", x, y, paint);
```

But this is what I see.

[image: The Oval is not blurred yet the text is blurred.]

Using android 4.0 sdk and testing on a 4.0.4 galaxy nexus device (UK). I'm wondering if this is a bug in 4.0.4 as I did test it on the emulator with 4.0 and 4.0.3 and it did blur perfectly well on them, unless I'm doing something completely wrong?

EDIT: Here is the extended View code to test it on other platforms.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BlurMaskFilter;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class BlurTestView extends View{

    private Paint paint;
    private Paint mShadowPaint;
    private int size = 100;
    private RectF mShadowBounds = new RectF();

    public BlurTestView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public BlurTestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public BlurTestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        paint = new Paint(0);
        paint.setColor(0xff333333);
        paint.setTextSize(size);
        paint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));

        mShadowPaint = new Paint(0);
        mShadowPaint.setColor(0xff333333);
        mShadowPaint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(10, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));

        mShadowBounds.top = size;
        mShadowBounds.bottom = mShadowBounds.top+(size /2);
        mShadowBounds.left = 0;
        mShadowBounds.right = (int)paint.measureText("hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawOval(mShadowBounds,mShadowPaint);
        canvas.drawText("hello", 0, size, paint);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing on a Galaxy Nexus running 4.0.4, only text is blurred, nothing else.  Running the same test app on my Gingerbread Incredible properly blurs all shapes and text.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me.  I reported it to the Android team; we'll see what they say.

It renders correctly if you set `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` on your Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Here is the official word from the Android graphics team:
"BlurMaskFilter is not supported with hardware acceleration."
(As of July 10, 2012)

Comment: Yes it does render correctly if hardware acceleration is set to false. But unfortunately I can't do that as the application uses hardware acceleration. Thank you for your reply though.

Comment: I think it is reasonable to use mostly hardware rendering but force software rendering on specific Activities that have trouble, as long as the performance is good.

Comment: You can disable HW acceleration on the VIEW level: myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

Comment: @chester1000 It's not in the public bug list, sorry.  But Romain Guy provided the answer, directly in response to this SO topic.

Comment: @Sparky: I was just wondering if I can "star" sth, to be notified on the status change. I solved my problem already using RadialGradient's :). Thanks for quick answer!

Comment: As of 2015, this fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Is this still an issue? So if we want to use both PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR and blur, we can't?

Answer (score 5):

If you can not disable hardware acceleration in your activity (for example it uses TextureView which require hardware acceleration) you can just call [setLayerType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayerType(int,%20android.graphics.Paint)) with first parameter [LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE) and the second parameter null for your view.

Like this

```
public class BlurTestView extends View {

    public BlurTestView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public BlurTestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public BlurTestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        // Disable hardware acceleration for this view
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); 

        // Perform other initialisation 
    }

    // Other methods and so on...
}
```

More info about mask filters, effects and shaders you can find [here](http://chiuki.github.io/android-shaders-filters/#/).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while adding a filter to a path.  I noticed that setting the target to 13 or below allows the filters to work.  14 and up they didn't.

```
android:targetSdkVersion="13"
```

Comment: Which is odd considering hardware acceleration was introduced in API 11.

Comment: Even stranger, when I mixed the view down to a bitmap, the new bitmap showed it with the blur in the copy.  Really odd.

Comment: So is there any alternative on how to achieve this blur effect without the blurmaskfilter? Setting the hw rendering OFF really slows down animations.

Comment: Not that I know of really.

Comment: This is normal behaviour, since the hardware acceleration is only turned on by default from API level 14 and up. See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html