# Blur effect when hardware acceleration is on

Tags: android, canvas, blur

Any idea how to draw circle with blur effect when the acceleration is turned on inside the manifest file  ?

Answer (score 0):

See the answers for [Android BlurMaskFilter has no effect in canvas.drawOval while text is blurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281404/android-blurmaskfilter-has-no-effect-in-canvas-drawoval-while-text-is-blurred)

The easiest solution is to disable hardware acceleration for the specific view that you need to draw the blur on with:

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Comment: Author clearly states they want to achieve the effect with acceleration turned *on*.

Comment: The question refers to HW acceleration being turned on in the *manifest file*, but my suggestion explains how to turn it off for a specific view - effectively overriding the manifest setting. It is quite common to have an app that generally benefits from HW accel but specific views that have issues with the limitations.