# How to change TexView Blur color created with BlurMaskFilter.Blur?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-paint

I want to change the (inner) blur of this TextView from white to another color using BlurMaskFilter.Blur

```
...
blurMaskFilterText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
BlurMaskFilter filter = new BlurMaskFilter((blurMaskFilterText.getTextSize()/10),BlurMaskFilter.Blur.INNER);
blurMaskFilterText.getPaint().setMaskFilter(filter);
```

This is what I got:

[image]

And this what I want:

[image]

How Can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

This post maybe what you looking for [Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281404/android-blurmaskfilter-has-no-effect-in-canvas-drawoval-while-text-is-blurred)

1. use paint and set desired color
2. use canvas and draw text