# Achieve setShadowLayer effect during drawCircle (or drawRoundRect) without turning off hardware acceleration

Tags: android

Currently, I have an app which support Android 2.3 and above.

In my custom view drawing operation, I need to drop shadow while drawing circle.

```
ballPaint.setShadowLayer(shadowSize, shadowSize, shadowSize, historyChartBallShadow);
canvas.drawCircle(px, py, this.ballSize, ballPaint);
```

I also understand that, with hardware acceleration turned on, I will not such shadow effect

[setShadowLayer Android API differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410195/setshadowlayer-android-api-differences)

However, I realize once hardware acceleration is turned off through `view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)`, my entire custom view drawing operation become very slow.

I was wondering, is there any other way to achieve similar shadow effect. **(A "blurred" black circle shadow)**

[image]

without turning off hardware acceleration?

p/s Even when I want to use `BlurMaskFilter` from [Android draw with blur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979955/android-draw-with-blur), I realize it doesn't support hardware acceleration too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had found a way to achieve such. First, we construct the ball + shadow off-screen image. Note, by using off-screen bitmap drawing technique, no GPU will be involved. The key is, don't use the `Canvas` from `onDraw` to perform `drawCircle`.

**Instead, construct our very own `Canvas`, backed by an off-screen bitmap.**

```
private Bitmap generateBallBitmap() {
    final int ballShadowSize = Utils.dpToPixel(BALL_SHADOW_SIZE);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(historyChartBallColor);
    paint.setShadowLayer(ballShadowSize, ballShadowSize, ballShadowSize, historyChartBallShadow);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)((ballSize + ballShadowSize)*2f), (int)((ballSize + ballShadowSize)*2f), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawCircle(ballSize, ballSize, ballSize, paint);

    return bitmap;
}
```

In custom view `onDraw` function, just draw the off-screen bitmap directly.

```
if (null == this.ballBitmap) {
    this.ballBitmap = generateBallBitmap();
}
canvas.drawBitmap(this.ballBitmap, px - this.ballSize, py, null);
```

For the entire process, I merely depend on the default value of layer type, without calling `setLayerType` explicitly.

The outcome is fast, yet shadow effect is visible too.

Comment: would you explain this lint "    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)((ballSize + ballShadowSize)*2f), (int)((ballSize + ballShadowSize)*2f), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
"